# html form input - multiple answers for each input field

Tags: html, mysql, arrays, forms, input

I'm not sure exactly how to word this question, but I'll do my best.
I have a form which collects data about employment history from users. At the moment my form looks like this:

```
<form name="EmploymentHistory" action="Form E.php" method="post">

    <h2>Employment History</h2>
        <label>Last/Current employer</label>
        <input type='text' name='LastCurrentemployer'>
<hr>    <label>Position</label>
        <input type='text' name='Position'>
<hr>    <label>Date Started</label>
        <input type='text' name='DateStarted'>
<hr>    <label>Date Finished</label>
        <input type='text' name ='DateFinished'>
<hr>    <label>Supervised by</label>
        <input type='text' name = 'Supervisedby'>
<hr>    <label>Contact Details for Boss</label>
        <input type='text' name='ContactDetailsForBoss'>

<hr>    <button type='button'>Add another job</button> <br>
<hr>    <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
```

My problem is that the "Add another job" button does nothing.
How can I enable a user to enter multiple jobs into their employment history so that each job is entered as a new record in my database, but the submit button (next) will only need to be hit once?

I was thinking about trying to set an array to then using arraypush to add each entry, eg:

```
$pastemployers = array ();
arraypush $pastemployers(POST_['LastCurrentemployer']);
```

then a loop to add each one as a new record, eg:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count(pastemployers); $x++){
echo "<input name='pastemployers" . $x . "' value='" . $pastemployers[$x] . "'> </input>";
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I can't find the answer online or work it out. Most of my searches are returning results about checkboxes or multiple submit buttons (not helpful to me). Please help

Comment: On click of the button you need to add required controls to the page and keep track of how many times the user has added it. This then has to be processed by your server side script. And one more thing, you need to change your field names from pastEmployers to pastEmployers_1, pastEmployers_2 and so on for each click

Comment: You can use javascript, everytime the user clicks on the "Add another job" the current form is sent to your server through ajax and a new form is generated. You should consider using `UPSERT`s to insert these jobs into your db one after another. Here is a similar example (of my own): [http://bvolley.herokuapp.com/](http://bvolley.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all alter your form as below and use addAnotherJob() to create clone of first span (using jQuery) and change id of each form field.On submitting this form you will get array of employer details.

```
<form name="EmploymentHistory" action="Form.php" method="post">

    <h2>Employment History</h2>
    <span class="span_clone">
        <label>Last/Current employer</label>
        <input type='text' id='LastCurrentemployer_0' name='LastCurrentemployer[]'>
<hr>    <label>Position</label>
        <input type='text' id='Position_0' name='Position[]'>
<hr>    <label>Date Started</label>
        <input type='text' id="DateStarted_0" name='DateStarted[]'>
<hr>    <label>Date Finished</label>
        <input type='text'  id='DateFinished_0' name ='DateFinished[]'>
<hr>    <label>Supervised by</label>
        <input type='text' id='Supervisedby_0' name = 'Supervisedby[]'>
<hr>    <label>Contact Details for Boss</label>
        <input type='text' id='ContactDetailsForBoss_0' name='ContactDetailsForBoss[]'>


<hr>    <button id='add-another-job-0' type='button' onclick= 'addAnotherJob()'>Add another job</button> <br>
</span>
<hr>    <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
```

Please refer this link : http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAECx/

Comment: Thanks heaps dhi_m! The link you posted is doing exactly what I want to do on my page! I have had a play with the code in jsfiddle and I think I am starting to understand, but when I copy paste the code into my editor and save the file it looses the "Add" function (not sure why). None-the-less you have been very helpful so far in setting me on the correct path. Thanks heaps.